# How to conform an array from another array that comes from a REST Service?

Tags: arrays, web-services, uitableview, for-loop, swift3

I’m trying to create a TableView with elements that comes from a REST Service, It’s a list of coupons that has description, title, category and images. So I deserialize the data first, put it in an array and then convert it into an specific array per each section, but my loop is not working, can anyone help me please?

This is my code:

```
    var couponsTitle : [String] = []

    var couponsDesc : [String] = []

    var couponsCat : [String] = []



    func getCoupons(){

        let miURL = URL(string: RequestConstants.requestUrlBase)

        let request =  NSMutableURLRequest(url: miURL!)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: miURL! as URL) {

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                let parseJSON = json

                let object = parseJSON?["object"] as! NSDictionary

                let mainCoupon = object["mainCoupon"] as! NSArray 

                let coupons = object["coupons"] as! NSArray



                for i in mainCoupon {
                    self.couponsCat.append((mainCoupon[i as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category"))
                }

                for i in coupons {
                    self.couponsCat.append((coupons[i as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category"))
                }

                for i in mainCoupon {

                    self.couponsDesc.append((mainCoupon[i as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: “description"))

                }



                for i in coupons {

                    self.couponsDesc.append((coupons[i as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: “description"))

                }

                for i in mainCoupon {

                    self.couponsTitle.append((mainCoupon[i as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: “name"))

                }



                for i in coupons {

                    self.couponsTitle.append((coupons[i as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: “name"))

                }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

        cell.couponTitle.text = couponsTitle[indexPath.row]
        cell.couponDescription.text = couponsDesc[indexPath.row].    
        cell.couponCategory.text = couponsCat[indexPath.row]
        return cell

}
```

My biggest issue is that I don’t know how to put in a loop the array but with the specification of each section (I mean, the title, description, category, etc.) Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having three arrays (one for each property), why not have a custom class for Coupon that has three properties?

```
class Coupon: AnyObject {

    var description: String
    var title: String
    var category: String

    init(description: String, title: String, category: String) {
        self.description = description
        self.title = title
        self.category = category
    }
}
```

If you do it that way, you can avoid so many loops by doing something like this

```
for coupon in mainCoupon {

            let description = mainCoupon["description"]
            let title = mainCoupon["name"]
            let category = mainCoupon["category"]

            let newCoupon = Coupon(description: description, title: title, category: category)

            couponsArray.append(newCoupon)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I was needing something like this

Comment: I have only one question, how do I have to declare the "couponsArray"? Because I have it like this: " var couponsArray : [String] = [] ", and it throws me an error that says: "cannot convert value of type 'Coupon' to expected argument type 'String'. Do you have a clue for this plz?

Comment: The error is telling you that you cannot add a Coupon to an array of Strings. The example array in your comment declares an array of Strings. What you need is an array of Coupons like this, "var couponsArray: [Coupon] = []". Then you should be able to add a Coupon to your array.

Comment: Ok, now I have an issue at the cellForIndexPath, because if I declare it as it was: "cell.couponTitle.text = couponsTitle[indexPath.row]" throws me this error: 'Cannot assign value of Type 'CouponsTitle' to type 'String?''... So the solution I've tried is: "cell.couponTitle.text = couponsTitle[indexPath.row] as AnyObject as? String", but still doesn't work. How can I solve it?